# Chome Extension - Programatically Trigger Pop Up

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

i am currently creating a chrome extension, i was able to create the popup.html and it works just fine, i was able to add a little authentication mechanism to it as well and it works just as expected. however there is something i am trying to achieve which at the moment seems impossible, but first let me explain the functionality of the extension

1. When i visit a particular link / site my content-script runs, it appends a button anywhere it see's the div class '.Post', i then add an event listener to the button that sends information such as the post title, URL and author of the post etc. now to where i need help.

Is it possible that when one click on the button it opens the Popup.html and sends these information to the popup.html.

Here is my code thus far.

content-script.js

```
$('.Post').append('<button id="the_id" class="add_archive_btn"> Add Archive </button>');
$('body').append('<style> .add_archive_btn { background: #ed665c; border: 0; border-radius: 3px; color: white; margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px; padding: 10px 20px; font-size: 13px; } </style>')
$('body').append('<script>function processData(){ alert("hi");}</script>')
```

Script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    whatToShow();
});

var userExtensionKey = 'blabla';

function whatToShow(){
    var data = localStorage.getItem(userExtensionKey);
    if(data !== null){
        $('.login_form').hide();
        $('.logged_in_layout').show();
    } else {
        $('.login_form').show();
        $('.logged_in_layout').hide();
    }
    
    
}

$('#revoked_access').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    localStorage.removeItem(userExtensionKey);
    $('.logged_in_layout').hide();
    $('.login_form').show();
});
                      
$('#click_action').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login"
        , type: 'POST'
        , data: {
            email: $('#lead_email').val(),
            password: $('#lead_password').val()
        }
        , dataType: 'json', // added data type
        success: function (res) {
            parseLogin(res)
        }
        , error: function (error) {
            printErrorMsg(error.responseJSON.error)
        }
    });
});

function printErrorMsg(msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    if (msg !== undefined) {
        var objt = Object.keys(msg);
        if (jQuery.inArray('email', objt) == "-1") {
            $('#email_input_filed').html('');
        } else {
            $('#email_input_filed').html('<div class="show_error_text">' + msg['email'][0] + '</div>');
        }
        
        if (jQuery.inArray('password', objt) == "-1") {
            $('#password_input_filed').html('');
        } else {
            $('#password_input_filed').html('<div class="show_error_text">' + msg['password'][0] + '</div>');
        }
        
        if (jQuery.inArray('loginfailed', objt) == "-1") {
            $('#login_failed').html('');
        } else {
            $('#login_failed').html('<div class="show_error_text_2">' + msg['loginfailed'][0] + '</div>');
        }
    }
}

function parseLogin(){
    // save login username
    localStorage.setItem(userExtensionKey, $('#lead_email').val());
    $('#lead_email').val('');
    $('#lead_password').val('')
    $('.login_form').hide();
    $('.logged_in_layout').show();
    console.log('saved user details succesfully');
}
```

Manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Hello Extensions",
  "permissions": [
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000/",
    "activeTab", 
      "tabs",
      "storage"
  ],
  "description" : "Base Level Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "hello.html",
    "default_icon": "hello_extensions.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "commands": {
    "_execute_browser_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+F",
        "mac": "MacCtrl+Shift+F"
      },
      "description": "Opens hello.html"
    }
  }, 
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["/js/background_script.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },    
  "content_scripts" : [
     {
      "matches": ["<all_url>"],
      "js": ["/js/jquery.min.js", "/js/content-script.js"],
      "permissions": [
          "activeTab", 
          "tabs",
          "storage"
        ]
     }
  ]
}
```

Please ignore the background.js script it is currently blank and has nothing inside, any help would be much appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Extensions can't open browser_action popup from the code. You can show a separate window using chrome.windows.create or you can show your entire UI in an iframe that points to a file in your extension, exposed via [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for your help man, by "entire UI" do you mean the pop up html ui , or a diffrent one, plus if i am to create a new window, can i pass in a url + query to the new window, if you have any code sample of this too, i would truly appreciate. thank you man, i really appreciate.